# Logout doesn't work when grouping routes by guest middleware

Tags: laravel

Using the built-in auth scaffolding, logout does not work when I assign the middleware `guest` to my logout route via a group.

Example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    // login routes
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // password reset routes
    Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

The logout simply does not work and throws no error.

I have removed the middleware from all controller `__construct()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to exclude it like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    // login routes
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
});

Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout')->middleware(['web', 'guest']);
```

Comment: I'm so dumb. I just had to move the logout route into my `auth` middleware group. I'll accept this though as it did point me in the right direction.